# ComboBox autocomplete in Tkinter does not work with non-English language. How can this be fixed?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, combobox

I found an example of the code for testing the algorithm on Stackoverflow. But I found that `AutoCompleteComboBox` does not add the rest of the word when entering into the list of words on a different keyboard layout.

This code with English list works well.

```py
from tkinter import *
from ttkwidgets.autocomplete import AutocompleteCombobox # pip install ttkwidgets


lst = [
    'C', 'C++', 'Java',
    'Python', 'Perl',
    'PHP', 'ASP', 'JS'
]

root = Tk()

# creating Combobox
combo_box = AutocompleteCombobox(root, width=30, completevalues=lst)

combo_box.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The Latin works:

[image]

When I use a string list in another language, Autocomplete Combobox does not work.

```py
lst = [
    'Хлеб', 'Картошка', 'Соль',
    'Молоко', 'Макароны',
    'Яйца', 'Мясо'
]
```

Cyrillic doesn't work☹️:

[image]

Comment: It works if you copy and paste the Unicode characters from the code into the entry box.  The strings in `lst` are Unicode characters, so the "M" in the input "Mяc" may be ascii "M", not the Unicode character "М" in 'Мясо' inside `lst`.

Comment: @acw1668 That is, when entering Cyrillic, the program perceives the entered character as ascii, but the list contains unicode strings, and a conflict arises when comparing. Did I understand correctly?
Why does such a conflict not arise when introducing Latin characters?

Comment: As I said, the input in the entry box is ASCII, not Unicode characters.  For Latin characters, ASCII is the same as Unicode, so it works.

Comment: the program is not using the character generated by the keypress for the autocomplete, rather it is using the symkey value of the physical key pressed. This resolves internally to an ASCII value. Tkinter does not use the OS input frameworks, rather it has primitive keyup/keydown processing within Tkinter, and autocomplete is using this.

Comment: @Andj It looks like using Autocompetecombobox from ttkwidgets is not feasible.. Do you know how to implement Cyrillic autocomplete in Tkinter in a different way?

Comment: @acw1668 I don't understand how it can be fixed. Do you know how to implement Cyrillic autocomplete in Tkinter in a different way?

Comment: As I said the auto-completion works if you can input the *required unicode characters* in the input box.

Comment: @acw1668, I did a test with a number of macOS, and even though I can type in the script the autocomplete code will not work on it. Will test on Linux to see if Behaviour is the same or different. It will adapt between ISO and ANSI layouts, and between AZERTY and QWERTY layouts for Latin script, haven't tested more exotic or custom Latin keyboard layouts yet.

Comment: The autocomplete functionality is using `tkinter.event.keysym` for handing keypresses.  if i press the Q key on a US-QWERTY keyboard I get the `keysym` value `q`, and the `char` value `q`. If I switch to a Greek layout I get `Greek_delta` and `δ`. For a Cyrillic layout, get `Cyrillic_em` and `м`. Latin script keyboards are processed completely different;y to Greek and Cyrillic. Since the `keysym` value is passed to match on, it can't match. Writing a custom version of the class using `event.char` instead of `event.keysym` may be a way forward. Will experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Okay probably not the best solution, but I made it work for my Bulgarian keyboard.

I went to the `tkautocomplete` module and first added a `print(event.keycode, end=", ")` in the `handle_keyrelease` method. Then I ran the file (which ran the test) and pressed all the letters on my keyboard, and after I closed the window I got my keycodes like this `81, 87, 69, 82, 84, 89, 85, 73, 79, 80, 219, 221, 220, 65, 83, 68, 70, 71, 72, 74, 75, 76, 90, 88, 67, 86, 66, 78, 77,`

Then in the `set_completion_list` method I added it as a set attribute like this

```
self.cyrilic_keycodes = set([81, 87, 69, 82, 84, 89, 85, 73, 79, 80, 219, 221, 220, 65, 83, 68, 70, 71, 72, 74, 75, 76, 90, 88, 67, 86, 66, 78, 77])
```

And lastly, in the `handle_keyrelease` method I added this

```
if event.keycode in self.cyrilic_keycodes:            
    self.autocomplete()
```

[Which makes it work in Bulgarian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zok0M.png)